PHP oci_execute wont return anything, when it should
I'm trying to implement a find by criteria method with OCI8 in PHP, where if the object has a parameter set, it should query all records, where the given parameters are like the ones in the record. But for some reason the query result is empty.
$id = $model->getId();

// create the criterias for each parameters
if (isset($id)) $crits[] = "ID = :id";
// ...

if (!empty($crits))
    //extend the sql with the criterias
    $sql .= " AND " . implode(" AND ", $crits);

    if (!$stmt = oci_parse($this->dataSource->getConnection(), $sql))
       throw new DataAccessException('parse ' . json_encode(oci_error($stmt)));
 
    // bind the required parameters
    if (isset($id) && !oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':id', $id, -1))
       throw new DataAccessException('bind id ' . json_encode(oci_error($stmt)));
    // ...
    
    if (!oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT))
       throw new DataAccessException('exec ' . json_encode(oci_error($stmt)));

    // handle result...
}

The sql must be correct, I copied the one assembled by the code, I did the binding manually, and got the correct results, so I think the problem should be in the binding.
I checked if the error handling is not correct, and the bindig does not actually happen, by removing them, but that cannot be the case, since then the oci_execute will throw an error.
Since checking the binded sql is not possible, I'm stuck.
Thanks for your help!

I don’t know much about oci8, but your question says that the execute function won’t return anything, and I’m seeing a lot of code. Can you simplify this to just one parameter? And don’t use POST/GET, just hard-code it.

What’s the error you get?

@b126 I don't get any error, it just wont query any records, when the same sql ran in for example sql developer does

You need to COMMIT in SQL Developer so that other connections to the database can see the data.

@ChristopherJones it's not the case, because when I select all values it works, the issue only happens when I try to bind parameters

I've found the issue, the value of $id is stored as string, but it was numeric, so I had to modify the binding like this:
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':id', $id, -1, is_numeric($id) ? SQLT_INT : SQLT_CHR);

